# Positioning a Navbar Below an Image

Tags: html, css, background-image, positioning

On my site, http://www.tokensofchange.org, the only way to position my navbar in the correct place is to use a margin-top style in the CSS.

```
.nav {
    margin-top:10.3%;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #050936;
    height:92px;
    float: right;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,108,255,0.35);
    }
```

If I remove the `margin-top: 10.3%`, the navbar is pushed up under the green buttons shown on the site. I am not sure if the background image is formatted incorrectly to push the navbar down:

```
.backgrounddiv {
    background: url('/images/Background_Index3.jpg');
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

The two buttons displayed do not have any margin styles included, so I am unsure why the navbar does not sit below the header with the background image, logo, and buttons. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a negative margin of `-9em` on the `.wrapper` div. Remove that and you can then remove the `margin-top:10.3%;` from your navigation.

I hope that helps